# T9 Algorithm too slow

Tags: java, regex, performance, t9

I am trying to implement T9 to my android [dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amanu.q.dialer). But it lags. I checked and generating the list of possible combinations is painless.

But I am trying to match using a pattern and I generated the pattern as follows

```
Pattern queryPattern;
List<String> names = T9Utils.possibleNames(query);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String name : names) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(name.toLowerCase());
    sb.append("(");
    sb.append(m.replaceAll("($0)\\s*"));
    sb.append(")");
    if (!name.equals(names.get(names.size() - 1))) {
        sb.append("|");
    }
}
queryPattern = Pattern.compile("(?i).*(" + sb.toString() + ").*");
for (CallLogItem contact : allContacts) {
   Matcher nameM = queryPattern.matcher(contact.displayName);
   Matcher phoneM = queryPattern.matcher(contact.phoneNumber);

   if (nameM.matches()) {
      //TODO: Highlighting
      toBeDisplayed.add(contact);
    } else if (phoneM.matches()) {
      toBeDisplayed.add(contact);
    }
}
```

The pattern generated would be something like

```
(?i).*(((g)\\s*(d)\\s*)|((g)\\s*(e)\\s*)|((g)\\s*(f)\\s*)|((g)\\s*(3)\\s*)|((h)\\s*(d)\\s*)|((h)\\s*(e)\\s*)|((h)\\s*(f)\\s*)|((h)\\s*(3)\\s*)|((i)\\s*(d)\\s*)|((i)\\s*(e)\\s*)|((i)\\s*(f)\\s*)|((i)\\s*(3)\\s*)|((4)\\s*(d)\\s*)|((4)\\s*(e)\\s*)|((4)\\s*(f)\\s*)|((4)\\s*(3)\\s*)).*
```

Comment: Why am i down voted! Tell me so that i can be better next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use a character class instead of all these alternations.

Then remove the whitespaces of the string you compare to. Take your name as an example: `Amanuel Nega` => `AmanuelNega`. You should use this conversion table (adapt it as needed):

```
Input   | Corresponding class
---------------------------
1       | [1.!]
2       | [2abc]
3       | [3def]
4       | [4ghi]
5       | [5klm]
6       | [6nop]
7       | [7qrst]
8       | [8uvw]
9       | [9xyz]
0       | [0+]
```

Let's say I type `4` followed by a `3` (which is what your output suggest).

Then the output will be `[4ghi][3def]`.

If I want to match `AmanuelNega` I'll have to type `2526835` which will produce the regex:

```
[2abc][5klm][2abc][6nop][8uvw][3def][5klm]
```

Which will be waaaay faster than what you already have

Comment: Thanks... How didn't i thought of that!